# SymPy's nullspace struggling when Mathematica succeeds with ease

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra, sympy

I have been trying to find the nullspace of a symbolic matrix `A` in SymPy using the command `A.nullspace`. Now the computation does not finish (or takes longer than I waited for) for the matrix I entered.

The strange thing is that Mathematica does this computation within a fraction of a second. I'll give the specific example I am using as Mathematica input code (should run)

```
L = ({{0, -I a Sqrt[b] Conjugate[g] Conjugate[w], 0, I a Sqrt[b] g w, 
 2 g2 + 2 b g z Conjugate[g], 0, 0, 0, 
 2 g2}, {-I a Sqrt[b] g w, -g2 - b g z Conjugate[g] - 
  I (-dD + b d g Conjugate[g]), -I DD, 0, I a Sqrt[b] g w, 0, 0, 
 0, 0}, {0, -I DD, I dD - g2, 0, 0, I a Sqrt[b] g w, 0, 0, 
 0}, {I a Sqrt[b] Conjugate[g] Conjugate[w], 0, 
 0, -g2 - b g z Conjugate[g] - 
  I (dD - b d g Conjugate[g]), -I a Sqrt[b] Conjugate[
   g] Conjugate[w], 0, I DD, 0, 0}, {0, 
 I a Sqrt[b] Conjugate[g] Conjugate[w], 
 0, -I a Sqrt[b] g w, -2 g2 - 2 b g z Conjugate[g], -I DD, 0, 
 I DD, 0}, {0, 0, I a Sqrt[b] Conjugate[g] Conjugate[w], 
 0, -I DD, -2 g2 + I b d g Conjugate[g] - b g z Conjugate[g], 0, 
 0, I DD}, {0, 0, 0, I DD, 0, 
 0, -I dD - g2, -I a Sqrt[b] Conjugate[g] Conjugate[w], 0}, {0, 0,
  0, 0, I DD, 
 0, -I a Sqrt[b] g w, -2 g2 - I b d g Conjugate[g] - 
  b g z Conjugate[g], -I DD}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, I DD, 
 0, -I DD, -2 g2}});

MatrixForm[L]
NullSpace[L]
```

As said for the same matrix SymPy is struggling. Is there any reason for this? Is there any other way to solve this problem in python?

---

Here is my SymPy code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import sympy as sp

a = sp.symbols("a", real=True, positive=True)
b = sp.symbols("b", real=True, positive=True)
g = sp.symbols("g", real=True, positive=True)
g2 = sp.symbols("g2", real=True, positive=True)
DD = sp.symbols("DD", real=True, positive=True)

dD = sp.symbols("dD", real=True)

w = sp.symbols("w")
z = sp.symbols("z")
d = sp.symbols("d")

L = sp.Matrix([[0, -1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 0,            1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, 
2*g2 + 2*b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g), 0, 0, 0, 
2*g2], [-1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, -g2 - b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g) - 
1j*(-dD + b*d*g*sp.conjugate(g)), -1j*DD, 0, 1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, 0, 0, 
0, 0], [0, -1j*DD, 1j*dD - g2, 0, 0, 1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, 0, 0, 
0], [1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 0, 
0, -g2 - b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g) - 
1j*(dD - b*d*g*sp.conjugate(g)), -1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(
g)*sp.conjugate(w), 0, 1j*DD, 0, 0], [0, 
1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 
0, -1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, -2*g2 - 2*b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g), -1j*DD, 0, 
1j*DD, 0], [0, 0, 1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 
0, -1j*DD, -2*g2 + 1j*b*d*g*sp.conjugate(g) - b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g), 0, 
0, 1j*DD], [0, 0, 0, 1j*DD, 0, 
0, -1j*dD - g2, -1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 0], [0, 0,
0, 0, 1j*DD, 
0, -1j*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, -2*g2 - 1j*b*d*g*sp.conjugate(g) - 
b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g), -1j*DD], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1j*DD, 
0, -1j*DD, -2*g2]]);

sp.pprint(L)
sp.pprint(L.nullspace())
```

According to a comment, the following inforamtion may be relevant too:

- Real, positive parameters: `a, b, g, g2, DD`
- Real parameters: `dD`
- Complex parameters: `w, z, d`

Comment: Mathematica is simply more efficient in this case (assuming the sympy code is correct). This shouldn't come as a surprise as you are comparing a commercial package with decades in development vs. an open source effort. However, note that you may help sympy if you provide attributes of the symbols such as "positive", "real", etc. Please post your python code as well.

Comment: Maybe Mathematica uses a different method to solve the task. You could have a look at sympy's source code to see how the problem gets solved there and then look at Mathematica's ... documentation or try to ask the company directly and then compare the two approaches.

Comment: @Stelios see edit for code. I did expect Mathematica to be more efficient, but the difference seems rather extreme (fraction of a second vs not working at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imaginary unit in sympy is `sympy.I` (not `1j`). Apparently, `1j` is acceptable by sympy, however, it is interpreted as a numercal quantity, which should be avoided in symbolic computations.

The following code gives the nullspace fairly quick. Note that I have also provided symbol attributes. These usually help sympy provide faster answers

```
a = sp.symbols("a", positive = True)
b = sp.symbols("b", positive = True)
g = sp.symbols("g", positive = True)
w = sp.symbols("w")
z = sp.symbols("z")
g2 = sp.symbols("g2", positive = True)
DD = sp.symbols("DD", positive = True)
dD = sp.symbols("dD", real = True)
d = sp.symbols("d")

L = sp.Matrix([[0, -sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 0,            sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, 
2*g2 + 2*b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g), 0, 0, 0, 
2*g2], [-sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, -g2 - b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g) - 
sp.I*(-dD + b*d*g*sp.conjugate(g)), -sp.I*DD, 0, sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, 0, 0, 
0, 0], [0, -sp.I*DD, sp.I*dD - g2, 0, 0, sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, 0, 0, 
0], [sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 0, 
0, -g2 - b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g) - 
sp.I*(dD - b*d*g*sp.conjugate(g)), -sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(
g)*sp.conjugate(w), 0, sp.I*DD, 0, 0], [0, 
sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 
0, -sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, -2*g2 - 2*b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g), -sp.I*DD, 0, 
sp.I*DD, 0], [0, 0, sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 
0, -sp.I*DD, -2*g2 + sp.I*b*d*g*sp.conjugate(g) - b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g), 0, 
0, sp.I*DD], [0, 0, 0, sp.I*DD, 0, 
0, -sp.I*dD - g2, -sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*sp.conjugate(g)*sp.conjugate(w), 0], [0, 0,
0, 0, sp.I*DD, 
0, -sp.I*a*sp.sqrt(b)*g*w, -2*g2 - sp.I*b*d*g*sp.conjugate(g) - 
b*g*z*sp.conjugate(g), -sp.I*DD], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, sp.I*DD, 
0, -sp.I*DD, -2*g2]]);

Ln = L.nullspace()
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! that works a lot better, runs in like 3 minutes. I guess Mathematica is just really impressive with its fraction of a second...

Comment: @Wolpertinger Thanks for the accept. BTW, the python code runs in less than 5 secs on my pc (i7, 8GB RAM).

Comment: whaaaat? now I'm confused, must be some problem with my pc then.
thanks for your help!! much appreciated.

Comment: one more question: which python version are you using? I ran this code on 2 computers now, and both gave around 3 minutes runtime, which is a factor of 36 compared to your result :( I am using python 2.7.13 on both of them though, maybe that is slower than the python 3 version?

Comment: @Wolpertinger I am using python 3.6 installed with anaconda distribution. Also using the latest sympy version (1.1.1)

Comment: hm, i have version (0.7.6.1). do you think that could be the difference?

Comment: @Wolpertinger Most probably.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151509/discussion-between-wolpertinger-and-stelios).